# How to overload a parentheses operator for both get and set?

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload a getter and setter using parentheses operator. When I try to use

```
double& my_vector::operator()(size_t index){
    return array[index]
}
```

This single operator overloading **works** for both the case:

eg: `my_vector(1) = 4.01;` & `double x = my_vector(1);`

But now I want to make getter as `const` and setter and `non-const` since I will be using const getter in another const function. I do

getter as  `double& my_vector::operator()(size_t index) const;`

setter as `double& my_vector::operator()(size_t index);`

I get 
Error: **functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded.**

I think I know what the error is talking about but I am not sure how to rectify it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. The error message does not match the code you show.

Comment: You'd want your const getter to return a `const double&` or just a `double`.

Comment: Yes that did work, Is there any benefit of using const reference (`const double&`) over just `double`

Comment: Returning a reference does just that, a reference to a piece of memory.  Returning a non-reference (and non-pointer) returns a copy.  In the case of returning `const double &`, you can't change the value returned by the function.  If you return by value (i.e., just `double`), then you can change it, albeit a copy.

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/99-overloading-the-parenthesis-operator/

Comment: why don't overload `[]`? That makes more sense than `()`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I have to use to for consistency purpose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a complete example which demonstrates how it works; (You can run this here http://ideone.com/kO0Rf1 )

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class my_vector {
public:
    double data[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    double & operator()(size_t i) {
        std::cout<<"Calling non-const ()"<<std::endl;
        return data[i];
    }
    double operator()(size_t i) const {
        std::cout<<"Calling const ()"<<std::endl;
        return data[i];
    }
};

void withConst(const my_vector &v) {
    double vv = v(0);
    std::cout<<"v(0) = "<<vv<<std::endl;
    // v(0) = 4.0; // Does not compile
}

void withNonConst(my_vector &v) {
    v(0) = 4.0;
    double vv = v(0);
    std::cout<<"v(0) = "<<vv<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
    my_vector vec;
    withConst(vec);
    withNonConst(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see you have used `double` for getter and not `const double&` I was just wondering why one would use one over the other?

Comment: Well you don't have to use const reference for primitive types, since copying them are cheap and makes more sense.

Comment: @MarsonMao ok that makes sense.

Comment: @pokche In general cases (such as when making a templated, generic class), you'll want to use `const T&`, because returning a reference is faster than copy constructing for most things.  When you know what type `T` is, though, and it isn't going to change, you can use whichever one you know is more efficient; if it's a built-in type, for example, returning a copy is usually at least as efficient as returning a `const T&`, and sometimes more efficient due to not having to dereference anything.

Comment: @JustinTime So if T is a heavy class and I want to return it by `const T&` what actually is it returning? What I am guessing is its returning the reference to where that T's object reside in memory and saying that you cannot write over it but can only look at it, print it or even if you want use this object to create a new object but never modify it. If you want to change it remove the const.

Comment: @JustinTime I think `const T&` show two face (or nature) .. one is what I have stated above and other is its also used to store a tmp variable, Don't really know where those tmp variable's location in memory is (I think its compiler dependent or at least that what I have heard) but hold on to it until the `const T&` itself goes out of scope.

Comment: @MarsonMao you can chime in if you want to rectify my comment :)

Comment: @pokche Mechanically, most compilers implement references as pointers, behind the scenes.  So, when you return a reference, you're actually returning a pointer (although the type system doesn't treat it as a pointer), it's just that the compiler handles all the messy syntax, null checks, and the like for you. Because of this, a reference can generally always fit in a single register, but comes with the cost of being dereferenced when you use it.  So, a `const T&` lets you read the referenced `T` directly, without copying it, but doesn't let you modify it; it acts a bit like a `const T* const`.

Comment: If you assign a `const T&` to a `T`, though, it'll copy the referenced `T`.  This is the same as what would happen if you assigned the referenced `T` to a `T` directly, or what would happen if you manually dereferenced a `const T* const` to the referenced `T`, and assigned that to a `T`.

Comment: (Note that not all compilers are guaranteed to implement references with pointers, it's just the most common way of implementing them.  And even if a compiler uses pointers to implement references, references will still be a distinct type from pointers.)